# What is the logic behind ISNUMERIC for certain special characters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The [`ISNUMERIC` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) has some unexpected behavior. The MSDN documentation says:

> `ISNUMERIC` returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0. Valid numeric data types include the following: **int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, numeric, money, smallmoney, float, real**.

And it also has a footnote:

> `ISNUMERIC` returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see [money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx).

Okay, so `+`, `-`, and listed currency symbols are expected to be considered numeric. So far so good.

Now for the odd part. First up, some of the currency symbols from linked article are *not* numeric, including:

- Euro-Currency sign, hex 20A0: `₠`
- Naira sign, hex 20A6: `₦`
- Rial sign, hex FDFC: `﷼`

This is weird, and I can't seem to find out why? Is this version or environment dependent?

However, things get weirder. Here are a few others I can't explain:

- `/` is not numeric, but `\` is (**Huh?!**)
- `REPLICATE(N'9', 308)` is numeric, but `REPLICATE(N'9', 309)` is not

The first and most basic question is: **what explains the above cases?** More importantly though: **what is the logic behind `ISNUMERIC`**, so I could explain / predict all cases myself?

Here's a good way to reproduce things:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(txt NVARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO @tbl (txt) 
VALUES (N''), (N' '), (N'€'), (N'$'), (N'$$'), 
       (NCHAR(8356)), (NCHAR(8352)), (NCHAR(8358)), (NCHAR(65020)), 
       (N'+'), (N'-'), (N'/'), (N'\'), (N'_'), (N'e'), (N'1e'), (N'e1'), (N'1e1'), 
       (N'1'), (N'-1'), (N'+1'), (N'1+1'), (N'⒈'), (N''), (N'¹'), (N'①'), (N'½'), 
       (N''), (REPLICATE(N'9', 307)), (REPLICATE(N'9', 308)), (REPLICATE(N'9', 309)), 
       (REPLICATE(N'9', 310));

SELECT  UNICODE(LEFT(txt, 1)) AS FirstCharAsInt,
        LEN(txt) AS TxtLength,
        txt AS Txt,
        ISNUMERIC(txt) AS [ISNUMERIC]
FROM    @tbl;
```

When I run this on my local Sql Server 2012 box I get the following results:

```
FirstCharAsInt   TxtLength   Txt        ISNUMERIC
---------------  ----------  ---------  ----------
NULL             0                      0
32               0                      0
8364             1           €          1
36               1           $          1
36               2           $$         0
8356             1           ₤          1
8352             1           ₠          0  --??
8358             1           ₦          0  --??
65020            1           ﷼‎          0  --??
43               1           +          1
45               1           -          1
47               1           /          0
92               1           \          1  --??
95               1           _          0
101              1           e          0
49               2           1e         0
101              2           e1         0
49               3           1e1        1
49               1           1          1
45               2           -1         1
43               2           +1         1
49               3           1+1        0
9352             1           ⒈         0
55356            2                     0
185              1           ¹          0
9312             1           ①          0
189              1           ½          0
55356            2                    0
57               307        /*...*/     1
57               308        /*...*/     1  --??
57               309        /*...*/     0  --??
57               310        /*...*/     0
```

Comment: The only ones that seem incorrect to me are that it falsely reports `0` for five of the values that actually cast fine to `money`. The others seem accurate. [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c1cc/2)

Comment: Though from `NCHAR(0) - NCHAR(65535)` I see 112 discrepancies. Including characters such as `₁,₂,₃,４,５,６,７,８,９` which look numeric but don't cast successfully to anything for me. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a74d8/1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The detailed behaviours of `ISNUMERIC` are not documented, and probably not fully known to anyone without source code access. That said, it may be that interpretation depends on the Unicode categorization (numeric or not). Equally, the weird cases you mention may be bugs that are preserved for backwards compatibility. Yes I know that sounds crazy, but it does happen.

As you are using SQL Server 2012, there is no need to use `ISNUMERIC`. Use [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) or the synonymous [`TRY_CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) instead to check if a string is convertible to a given type. Where they provide adequate functionality, these are preferable to [`TRY_PARSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx), because the latter involves more expensive processing via CLR integration.

Comment: And probably not fully known to a lot of the people with source code access, either. :-) Wish I could +1 again for the second paragraph. ISNUMERIC() is largely useless because its intention is to determine whether something can be converted to at least one numeric type; it is obviously much more important to know that you can convert to a single, specific numeric type.

Comment: @AaronBertrand There seems to be a reasonably significant number of cases where it does not even meet that intention too.

Answer (score 9):

The ASCII backslash (code point 5C) happens to share the same code point as the yen sign (¥) in the Shift-JIS encoding used by the Japanese version of Windows, and the won sign (₩) in Korean EUC-KR. Hence, it is very likely just a continuation of the currency sign theme.

Comment: Ah that's an interesting theory. It is `money` that it casts to as well.

Comment: @Jeroen - [It's on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A5) FWIW

Comment: @Jeroen I'm afraid not. Switch the legacy code page of your Windows installation to Japanese and you get paths such as `C:¥Program Files¥` in explorer.exe